# SQL - Convert varchar (dd/mm/yyyy hh.mm AM/PM) to datetime

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a varchar field to datetime. The data in the varchar field looks like this `dd/mm/yyyy hh.mm AM/PM`.

I'm actually trying to extract the date part & time part and convert them to date and time respectively.

And I use the below query to extract the date part from the varchar and convert it to date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT([Start Date], 10)
    ,CASE WHEN ISDATE(LEFT([Start Date], 10)) = 1 
        THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT([Start Date], 10), 120)
    END
    ,ISDATE(LEFT([Start Date], 10))
FROM [dbo].[TestTable]
```

I have timestamp in the format mentioned above for entire August.

But the query gives me the result in `yyyy-dd-mm` format and the date are converted to date format only till 12 Aug'15. Date after 12 of Aug is null. I know it's because, in the case statement they are returned 0. How can I convert those values also to date?

Any suggestions to convert all the values to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's failing after 12th august, that suggests that it's getting the conversions wrong and is interpreting days as months and months as days. Since there's no 13th month, that's why it fails.

Comment: Use `SET DATEFORMAT  YMD`, [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2659/0)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Yes, that's what happening. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @lad2025 - Thanks that was very simple. I used the `FORMAT()` and converted the date to `yyyy-mm-dd` format, but is there a solution to convert the date after 12 Aug'15 to actual date?

Comment: @UnknownUser Set correct DATEFORMAT before doing conversion and it will work.

Comment: The days and months are switched. You don't see anything after 12th of august because there is no 13th+ month. Use the correct date format.

Comment: specify excatly the conversion to apply, use `CONVERT(datetime,[chardate],103)`  then other server settings such as dateformat won't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SET DATEFORMAT` as lad2025 suggested.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Or you can use the following in your `CONVERT()`

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(16) = '13/08/2015 11:13';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @date, 103)
```

[103 is the code for dd/mm/yyyy.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: the code which is defined at the last specified which format we need the date? Or the current format of the date?

Comment: In your question you're saying that you use the format `dd/mm/yyyy `. That should match the format 103. The format should match what is stored in @date for my example, or `[Start Date]` in your code.

Comment: style number 103 does convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM into datetime. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d925/1

Comment: @JodyT - Thank you very much. It did help me. And @Used_By_Already - Thank you too, my time format is <code>hh.mm AM/PM</code> but I used the replace function and replaced the `.` with `:` and used the function which JodyT given and now I have the result in my desired format. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had missed he period (as opposed to colon) - sorry. but your replace clearly fixed that - well done.